# addArc() using path default margin/padding

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-studio-2.1

I have created semi-circle using addArc() but there is strange gap between arc & rectangle as shown in image below. How to remove that gap around arc.

**Here is my output image link.**
[image]

```java
int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    path.reset();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
    //path.moveTo(0, getHeight() - 100);
    int h = (getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - (getMeasuredHeight() /2) - 100;
    path.addArc(new RectF(50, h, getMeasuredWidth()-50, getMeasuredHeight()-50), 0, 180);
    path.close();


    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
```

Comment: what is `paint.getStyle()` ? `FILL_AND_STROKE`  or `FILL`?

Comment: Currently default style is applied.

Comment: this is because of "inverse" `Path.FillType`, you cannot avoid that imho